# Foundation 6: Hide the Top Bar when link is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm using Foundation 6 for a one-page website. And I'm using a Top Bar to take users to different sections of the website. So when visiting the website on mobile, when I click a link from the collapsed Top Bar, I want the Top Bar to hide after taking the user to a certain section of the website.

Here's my HTML:

```
<div data-sticky-container>
   <div data-sticky data-sticky-on="small" data-options="marginTop:0.9;" style="width: 100%">

     <div class="top-bar">
      <div class="top-bar-title">
        <span data-responsive-toggle="responsive-menu" data-hide-for="medium">
          <span class="menu-icon dark" data-toggle></span>
        </span>
      </div>
      <div id="responsive-menu">
        <div class="top-bar-section">
            <ul class="menu" data-magellan>
                <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#home">HOME</a></li>
                <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#events">EVENTS</a></li>
                <li class="title"><a class="title-link" href="#about">ABOUT</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

   </div>
</div>
```

I could have achieved this functionality by using this (I think):

```
$(function () {
        $('.title-link').on('click', function () {

            $("#responsive-menu").css({display: none});

        });
    });
```

But the problem is when I click the menu icon, Foundation adds and inline style of `display: block;` and I can't seem to change it through to JS.

Is there a way to override the inline styles, or should I use a different layout? Thanks for the help!

Comment: `$("#responsive-menu").css({"display": "none"});` should work.

Comment: As I said, Foundation is adding an inline style of display: block, and because of that the script doesn't work.

Comment: `.css()` overrides inline style, you just forgot `"` in your code. Read here : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769378/how-to-override-inline-css-through-javascript

Comment: It works! Thank you for pointing that out!

Comment: so i'm going to make it as an answer :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.css()` overrides inline style. Just change this line :

```
$("#responsive-menu").css({display: none});
```

To :

```
$("#responsive-menu").css({"display": "none"});
```

Similar topic for more info : [How to override inline css through javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769378/how-to-override-inline-css-through-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Try this one:

**JS:**

```
$(function () {
        $('.title-link').on('click', function () {

            $("#responsive-menu").toggleClass('myStyle');

        });
    });
```

**CSS:**

```
.myStyle {
display: block!important;
}
```

or

```
.myStyle {
display: none!important;
}
```

depend what you want to do.

Comment: This just works for the first time. As '!important' is being used, when I click the menu icon again, the top-bar doesn't appear.

Comment: So remove `!important` , in fact I don't understand what you want to do. if you create a fiddle I can help you more.