# How to override inline styles with !important using jquery?

Tags: jquery, html

I have a:

```
<p style="color:red !important;">sample text here</p>
```

and then I want to override that style in JQuery, how would I do it?

using `!important` in CSS obviously doesn't work(but tried it anyway).
I'm thinking if I can do something like:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('p').css("color","#fff");
});
```

any thoughts on this??

Comment: it is being overriden what do you expect?

Comment: well the jquery didnt work for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code is correct, you can do it exactly like you suggested. Even though there is an inline style rule already on the element, once the document is ready, it will replace that rule with what you've written, [see here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1769378/how-to-override-inline-css-through-javascript).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/307kmo51/)**

If for some reason, you want more assurance, you can clear the inline styling before you apply the new styling with the [`removeAttr()`](https://api.jquery.com/removeAttr/) jquery method (but it's a bit of a waste of code).

**[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/307kmo51/2/)**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
 $('p').removeAttr('style');
  $('p').css("color","blue");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p style="color:red !important;">sample text here</p>
```

Comment: yes, my code didnt work for me until i removed the style attribute. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Simply first unset/remove the color using the style like below,then set the color

```
$('p').css('color', '')
```

Set the color once again which you want

```
$('p').css('color','green');
```