# Override internal stylesheet of element which is created dynamically

Tags: javascript, css, angularjs

I have a `angularjs` component, third party library creates the `canvas` inside the component's html file. 
Following is the `canvas` created by third party library on page load.

```
<canvas style="width: 410px; height: 450px;"></canvas>
```

My current solution is, I am setting changing the `CSS` following way inside `$postLink` callback method.

```
var elem= angular.element(document.querySelector('#fooSelector canvas'));    
elem.css('width', '420px');
```

But I read somewhere changing `CSS` and Manipulating `DOM` inside `angularjs` `controller` is not a good practice.

So How can I change `inline CSS` of element which is created dynamically by some third party library

Comment: Use `!important` to override the internal css..

Comment: this post will help you. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50116505/how-to-change-property-of-ul-tag-css-in-html/50116657#50116657

Answer (score 0):

> changing CSS and Manipulating DOM inside angularjs controller is not a
>   good practice

This is just a common statement for beginners, this does not mean you can not or you should not - this means you should not if there is better and easier way.

When you create component that main purpose is wrap something like canvas, it is absolutely normal to change its position, width or whatever.

Though using query selector is not good - imagine you have 2 such components on page, then you will always select first canvas. So it is better to use $element.find:

```
$element.find('canvas').css('width', '420px');
```